# What's the best method of finding integers in a string?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello StackOverflow community! I'm student trying to solve this problem....
The main issue I am having with it is that I dont know the best way to find characters that are valid integers in Strings. 
Note: I am only 1 month into learning Java, and I spent most of last year learning python. So compiler languages are new to me.
Write a program that reads in a product code and outputs whether it is valid or not based on some simple rules.

The rules:
1st part can contain only capital letters and 6 digits. 2nd part is alldigits and = the product of the first 6 digits taken in groups of two from the left.

eg: AX6BYU56UX6CV6BNT7NM  287430
is valid because 65*66*67 = 287430

This is what I have so far

```
import java.util.*;                       //import java utilities
public class Basic5{                      //declares my class
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);//creates Scanner for user input
        String userentry=kb.nextLine();   //Takes users input as a string     
        String result="Valid";            //Variable for if the code is Valid
        int DoubleCounter=0;              //Counter for number of ints
        double newdouble;                 
        List<Double> NumberList =  new ArrayList<Double>(); //Creates Array List for tracking Doubles
        for(int i=0;i<userentry.length();i++){              //checks length of Users input
            if(Character.isLowerCase(userentry.codePointAt(i))){  //checks if its a Lowercase letter
                result="Fail";                              //Changes result variable
            if(Integer.parseInt(userentry,i)){              //checks if character from input is a valid integer
                DoubleCounter+=1;                           //Adds to DoubleCounter
                newdouble=userentry.charAt(i);              //Isolates character
                NumberList.add(newdouble);                  //Adds it to List of doubles
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first part of the input are there any specific positions for numbers or it can be any position/index ?

Comment: Watch out Integer.parseInt can do exception.. which will break your code, try  catch

Comment: And how would you define "best method" in your specific context? This is a course, so you should consider methods that correctly reflect the course's content and priorities... Also, consider how you would have solved this problem in other languages you are familiar with, like Pyhton. Would you have considered using regex patterns for that? Iterate over string's characters? The fact that Java is compiled is rarely significant to the resolution of an algorithmic question. You have to abstract the language out of your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
@Test
public void testExample() {
    assertTrue(isValid("AX6BYU56UX6CV6BNT7NM 287430"));
    assertFalse(isValid("AX6BYU56UX6CV6BNT7NM 287431"));
}

private boolean isValid(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split(" ");
    int[] ints = extractIntegers(parts[0]);
    int target = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    return product(ints) == target;
}

private int[] extractIntegers(String s) {
    String digits = s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
    int[] ints = new int[digits.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i += 2) {
        ints[i / 2] = Integer.parseInt(digits.substring(i, i + 2));
    }
    return ints;
}

private int product(int[] ints) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int num : ints) {
        result *= num;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It assumes that there are non-zero even number of digits in the first part of the string. If you need to handle other cases, it should be easy to do, based on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following methods to check whether the input is a char or digit :

```
Character.isDigit('A');
Character.isLetter('A');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "AX6BYU56UX6CV6BNT7NM 287430";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "");
```